# IFrame player API only play audio with no video on samsung galaxy S3

Tags: jquery-mobile, video, youtube-api

I'm using jquery mobile + phonegap to build android and ISO applications.
One of my pages contains videos that loaded from youtube,
The page present thumbnail and while the user click on it I'm calling to the following method:

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(videoId, element){
  player = new YT.Player(element, {
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
  videoId: videoId,
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady  
    }
  });    
}
```

NOTE: in my code I'm not using `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` only the customized one that I'm directly calling.
This is working fine! the only issue that I saw is on Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.0.4) there I can hear the video but cannot see it unless I'm expanding the video to full screes.
IFrame player API uses the compatible player so why I'm facing this issue here? what can be done?